# What are the default protection levels of different bindings in wcf

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I gone through the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347692.aspx) Document, and found the following : -

[image: Protection Levels]

But they had not mentioned the default protection level of each binding.

Can any one let me know the default protection level of each binding.

Comment: that picture looks awful - I cant read the text. Did you see [How to: Set the ProtectionLevel Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347791.aspx) and here [ProtectionLevel Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.protectionlevel.aspx)

Comment: @JeremyThompson, as I know its difficult to read the text in a picture, thats the reason I and attached the link of the same. Well I guess the question is not cleared (may be I am not good to explain it properly). Well, I don't want to know that how to sent the protection level or what are the types of protection levels....but instead, I would like to know the default protection level of each binding....

Comment: Yeah as I mention in my answer there is no default, its up to you to choose. I think its None. I will find a doco and update my answer.

Comment: @JeremyThompson, Nope, if you look at the highlighted text in picture(or else go through the link and match the highlighted text there in), you can see it is said : binding that enables/applies security and you didn't specified protection level then it will encrypted and signed.....So which binding enabled or applies security at message level...in this way we can figure out the default protection level....I guess WSHTTPBINDING....has default security enabled....then what is "applies security at message level and do not specify protection level"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the Protection Level depending on your needs, I dont think its a case of this goes best with that, it depends on your situation.

**None** - Authentication only.
**Sign** - Sign data to help ensure the integrity of transmitted data.
**EncryptAndSign** - Encrypt and sign data to help ensure the confidentiality and integrity of transmitted data.

In the article its mentions:

> If you select a binding that does not have security enabled (for
>   example, the BasicHttpBinding class has security disabled by default),
>   and the ProtectionLevel is not explicitly set, then none of the
>   application data will be protected.

Hence if you choose a binding that has, for example, disabled security by default and you dont explictly set the ProtectionLevel - **none of the data will be protected - and that's what I mean there is no default**.

Edit: This article has a couple of tables that shows you the comparison and should hopefully sort out the confusion: [Configuring System-Provided Bindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731092.aspx)

Comment: fine, but what about -  "applies security at message level and do not specify protection level". can you highlight any of binding which applies security at message level ....  but the highlighted text in the picture seems confusing....what is default enabled and applies security?